# Modal Logic Question

Tags: modal-logic

I am currently reading a paper and the following statement is used:

```
Fact "A" for individual i happens if and only if condition B is fulfilled for i possibly not, though not necessarily exclusive of, j.
```

What does this mean? (speficially,the not, though not part)

Thats exactly how its written; I only removed the technicalities. I do not know if it concerns modal logic or if its a typo, but I never came around such statement.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question? And by technicalities do you mean you replaced actual words with "Fact A", "individual i", etc?

Comment: I was following until " possibly not, though not necessarily exclusive of, j."

Comment: Backing up before understanding the sentence - I'm not sure how to parse that grammatically.

Comment: @Marcelo can you show us more context around that quote? As written, it's not well-formed English.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the paper has created two people named 'i' and 'j', and that caused the confusion.  If I substitute Alice and Bob into that I get

> Fact "A" for Alice happens if and only if condition B is fulfilled for Alice possible not, but not necessarily exclusive of Bob."

That's getting better, but I'd reword it as

> Fact "A" for Alice happens if and only if condition B is fulfilled for Alice.  This is independent of any other observer: Fact "A" can happen for Alice, even if condition B does not happen for Bob.